# Recursion inside a class to calculate factorial

Tags: python

What's wrong with the code? This is correct if I don't use class. If I use class, I get an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *:'int' and 'factorial'

```
class factorial(object):
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number = number
    def factorial(self):
        if self.number == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            result = self.number * factorial(self.number-1)
            return result

def main():
    fac = factorial(5)
    print(fac.factorial())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The issue is with  result = self.number * self.factorial(self.number-1) i have modified the code to work in my answer. effectively you are passing 2 arguments to function and also you should be calling this function using self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same name for a class `factorial` and one of its methods `factorial(self)` and I think that's the origin of your problem. When you write:

```
result = self.number * factorial(self.number-1)
```

You hope that result will get the value of `self.number` multiplied by the factorial of `self.number-1`. But for the Python interpreter, `factorial(self.number-1)` is not a number but an object (actually a wrapper for an int). If you write:

```
result = self.number * factorial(self.number-1).factorial()
```

You call the method `factorial` on the object `factorial` and everything works fine.

But as you did in your own answer, you don't need a class here.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is trying to point you in the direction that you are attempting to do something that the python interpreter does not know how to do. The error is unsupported operand types for int and factorial. So, in your code, you are attempting to execute the following line:

```
result = self.number * factorial(self.number-1)
```

So, in the line, you are attempting to multiply an int (self.number) by an object factorial(self.number-1). You are calling a factorial constructor, not attempting to run factorial on number - 1. In order to make this work, you need to multiply by another number, not a an object (type factorial).

Answer (score 0):

I have made minor modification to your code added code in else block.

```
class factorial(object):
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number = number
    def factorial(self):
        if self.number == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            self.number -= 1
            result = self.number * self.factorial()
            return result

def main():
    fac = factorial(5)
    print(fac.factorial())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

HI @bogortron and @Manoj, 
I got the correct reason and answer but the thing I don't understand is, this works fine when I just use function:

```
def factorial(number):
    if number == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        result = number * factorial(number-1)
        return result  
print(factorial(5))
```

This code runs and give result right.

Comment: Python does not know how to multiply an integer value with an instance of factorial. Since the factorial3 function returns a number, python knows how to multiply to number types